# formulario con php

Tags: php, mysql, html5

espero estén bien :).
Bueno estaba intentando validar un login a lo cual ya me resulta pero el mensaje de error que le puse al else me imprime en la web, no debería ser asi. El mensaje ya se debería ver cuando ingreso datos incorrectos. Espero me puedan ayudar se los agradecería mucho :). El primero es donde realizo la validación y el otro es el formulario.

```
> Validación

    <?php
include('db.php');
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;


$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdtienda");

$consulta="SELECT*FROM usuario where nombre='$usuario' and contraseña='$contraseña'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
  
    header("location:pagina.php");

}else{
    include("index.php");
    ?>
    <h1>No ingreso</h1>
    <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);




> Formulario


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cabecera.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <form action="validar.php" method="post">
   <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Sistema de login</h1>
   <p>Usuario <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese su nombre" name="usuario"></p>
   <p>Contraseña <input type="password" placeholder="ingrese su contraseña" name="contraseña"></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
   
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberías comprobar si realmente conectas a la base de datos, y también si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente o produce algún error. Por otro lado, tu código es altamente sensible a inyección SQL, deberías escapar las variables o usar prepared statements. Me imagino que estás empezando, no estaría mal que buscases material más actualizado para aprender, PHP tiene el problema de que muchos de los recursos y manuales disponibles son demasiado viejos. Quizá no te vendría mal empezar directamente con un framework como Laravel. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que nada mas entrar a  la web estas realizando la consulta.
para solucionarlo debes:

1- asignar la propiedad `name` al boton login

```html
<input type="submit" name="btnlogin" value="Ingresar">
```

2. preguntar en el código `php` si se ha hecho click en el boton.

```html
<?php
session_start(); //esta linea siempre primero al crear el documento
include('db.php');


if(isset($_POST[btnlogin])){

  $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
  $contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];

  $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdtienda");
  $consulta="SELECT*FROM usuario where nombre='$usuario' and contraseña='$contraseña'";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

  $filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

  if($filas){
    
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
    header("location:pagina.php");

  }else{
    include("index.php");
    echo "<h1>No ingreso</h1>";
  
  }
  mysqli_free_result($resultado);
  mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

NOTA: debes replantear la lógica del login